# Cuándo usar "linea de tiempo" o "calendario"

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, vocabulario-técnico

Quiero traducir la palabra "timeline" de inglés al español pero no entiendo las diferencias entre algunas de las opciones. El contexto de "timeline" en este caso es la frase:

> What is the project timeline?

Revisé www.reverso.net que me aconsejó dos opciones. Una es "línea de tiempo", tal como:

> La profundidad de las contusiones nos da una **línea de tiempo**.

y la otra es "calendario", tal como:

> Es importante que haya un **calendario** específico para el proceso
>   político.

Según los ejemplos arriba, "calendario" me parece mejor para lo que quiero traducir. Sin embargo, no me queda claro si realmente tenga razón en pensar así o si las dos opciones se pueden intercambiar. ¿Hay diferencias sutiles entre las dos traducciones que le hace a una mejor ajustada para ciertos contextos?

De antemano agradecidos por su apoyo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personalmente asocio más *línea de tiempo* con una exposición gráfica de sucesos históricos, como puede encontrarse en un libro de texto o en la pared de un museo (un sinónimo de esto sería una *cronología*).

Por otra parte, *calendario* no me transmite la misma connotación de urgencia que *timeline* (quizá porque asocio inconscientemente *timeline* con *deadline*). Más bien sugiere algo planteado con anticipación y tranquilidad, como un calendario anual donde los días festivos ya están determinados por ley hace años.

El contexto de las frases de tus ejemplos influye mucho. Quizá "project timeline" se pueda traducir mejor como *agenda del proyecto*. Ya que etimológicamente *agenda* significa "lo que debe hacerse", la palabra sugiere metas a futuro que deben cumplirse en un determinado plazo.

En el caso de las contusiones, no estoy seguro de cuál es el contexto, pero si se trata de algo relacionado con la medicina forense, *línea de tiempo* suena bastante bien. *Línea temporal* también funcionaría.

En cuanto al proceso político, *calendario* me parece muy adecuado: se trata de elecciones, que son asimilables a festividades o eventos cívicos, fijados de antemano; no son metas urgentes sino puntos en el tiempo.

Comment: De hecho, al _timeline_ de las preguntas de [se] se le llama _línea de tiempo_ en su traducción para [es.so]. Véase [un ejemplo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/1833/timeline)

Answer (score 1):

Yo diría

> cronología

en ambos ejemplos.  Porque la cronología nos dice cuándo hacer qué, o cuándo sucedió cada cosa.

Answer (score 0):

`Cronograma`

En el contexto de un proyecto, la frase `"What is the project timeline?"` podría traducirse como: `"¿Cuál es el cronograma del proyecto?"`

En un proyecto, el cronograma es la manera en que se organizan las tareas correspondientes y el tiempo en el que se realizarán, así como el tiempo que se tardará en hacerlas.